# Error Building Maven project when I do maven install

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, webui

I'm trying to build a Maven Project using Spring Tool Suit from Eclipse and I'm having an error when I do the Maven Install.

First I do the Maven Clean and it works properly but when I do the maven install this error appears:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:regex-properties 
  (set-properties-with-regex) on project qad-webshell-pom: 
  Execution set-properties-with-regex of goal 
  org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:regex-properties failed:
  Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1 or 
  one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
  Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:jar:1.9.1 -> 
  org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4: Failed to read artifact descriptor 
  for org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4: 
  Could not transfer artifact org.beanshell:bsh:pom:2.0b4 from/to 
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
  Cannot access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 with type default 
  using the available connector factories: 
  BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: 
  Cannot access http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 using the registered transporter
  factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR]   roleHint: http'
```

Comment: You could add pom.xml, it would help to get why error occurs.

Comment: You have either network/firewall/proxy issue or some very bad configuration issue...

Comment: Thank you, I think it was an error with the Maven servers because after a couple of days it was working without issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I have restarted Eclipse, then go on the project specific maven module in which you have the error, right click > Maven > Update Project ...

After the Update on the specific module the Maven install  worked without any error.